# Android Beacon Library Reference Application Help (didEnterRegion function)

Tags: ibeacon, eddystone

My region is:

```
Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", Identifier.parse("24DDF411-8CF1-440C87CD-E368DAF9C93E"), null, null);
```

When I start the program I get this message:

```
06-26 18:03:21.061 7394-7394/? D/BeaconReferenceApp: setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving
```

But it doesn't enter in any `didEnterRegion` function

So, I removed this line: `backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);`

And change scanning times, as it follows:

```
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000l-1100l);
```

I checked my Beacon UUID and they are `24DDF411-8CF1-440C87CD-E368DAF9C93E`

So what is wrong? Why the app doesn't go to the `didEnterRegion` function?

I already made it work to work with other than AltBeacons... (ranging function works ok!)

My final goal is to get current time when a beacon is discovered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few possibilities:

1. If you are *already* in the beacon region, you won't get a second callback until the beacon disappears (turn it off for 30 seconds or so, then turn it back on while the app is running.)  Alternatively, you can look for a call do `didDetermineStateForRegion` which is always called when your app starts up, with a flag that tells you if you are inside or outside.
2. Make sure you have granted runtime permissions to location.
3. Make sure location is turned on for your phone in settings.
4. Make sure the beacon is transmitting that identifier using the Locate app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en
5. Make sure you have the proper BeaconParser configured.  The question is tagged Eddystone, but shows an iBeacon or AltBeacon-style UUID as the first identifier.  Do you have a custom beacon parser configured?  What beacon type are you trying to detect?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just one question why the location is turned on? This way battery wont be consumed even faster?

Comment: As of Android 6, Google requires that location be enabled by the user so that an app may scan for Bluetooth beacons.  The reason has to do with privacy -- because beacons can be used to infer location, they want the user to be able to opt-in and out of this easily.  To be clear, the location setting just makes it so beacon scanning and GPS *can* be on.  It doesn't necessarily mean they both will be on.  So there is not necessarily any extra battery drain.

Comment: Thanks, how does this didDetermineStateForRegion changes during application? When it enteres in a region it is called and when a beacon leaves it is called as well? There is no difference between going in or going outside? I would need to differentiate this two behaviour do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There is a parameter passed to the method that tells you if you are inside the region or outside.

Comment: When the beacon is discovered and app is running at background it runs the 'didEnterRegion' and when the program is running at foreground the 'didDetermineStateForRegion' is run? Another question is if I want to show time HH:MM discover time what should I do? BeaconReferenceApplication doesnt have a layout should I call monitor class and pass as parameters or create a layout to BeaconReferenceApplication and write a TextView in there? How does the BeaconReferenceApplication doesnt have a layout?

Comment: didEnterRegion is only called when the beacon is detected after some period of not being detected by the same app.  If you simply restart the app, you will not get a didEnterRegion if it was detected if the app was previously running.  The reference application does have a layout here:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_monitoring.xml

Comment: You're right that is the BeaconReferenceApplication layout but why is setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring); called in the monitoring_activity and not in the BeaconReferenceApplication?

Comment: A global Android Application class is not an Activity, so it has no layout.  Read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html